# windows batch command to copy files from a list of folders to a destination without traversing through the subfolders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need to recursively go through a list of windows directories and copy the txt files in these directories to a destination.I am using the below code:

```
@echo off

set TESTDIRS=RFP,New Audit
set TD=C:\Users\Audit

for %%d in (%TESTDIRS%) do call :process_testdir %%d
goto :eof

:process_testdir
set CTD=%TD%\%1
echo CTD: %CTD%
    REM Echos the expected path

for /R %CTD% %%f in (*.txt) do (echo %%f
 copy "%%f" "C:\Users\Audit\ImportantDocs)
    REM Echos as expected

goto :eof
```

Issue that i am facing:This batch script traverses across all the subfolders present within the parent folder and copies the txt files into the destination,which is not what i want.If i specify a folder name,i would want the text files only in that particular folder to be copied to the destination and not the files present in its subfolders.
Eg:The folder named "RFP" contains 3 text files and also a subfolder named "July" which contains 5 test files.I would want my batch script to copy only the 3 files present in the "RFP" folder to the destination and not the 5 files present in the subfolder "July"

Any help ??

Answer (score 1):

change

```
for /R %CTD% %%f in (*.txt) do (echo %%f
```

to

```
for %%f in ("%CTD%\*.txt") do (echo %%f
```

the `/r` is recursive. Your directorynames appear to include spaces, so you'd need to "enclose directorynames including spaces in quotes" and remove he quotes in the subroutine by using `%~1` which removes the enclosing quotes.

Comment: Thank you.This worked for me.Being extremely new to Windows batch scripts i end up asking questions which seem really silly.:(